# Is Android Cloud 2 Device Messaging (C2DM) compatible with Google's 2-step verification?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, android-c2dm

I've been reading up on Android's cloud 2 device messaging (C2DM) and all the documentation mention ClientLogin as the authentication method. However the [ClienLogin](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html) info page specifically states its not compatible with 2-step verification and recomments using OAuth2. 
Can I use OAuth2 as a replacement for ClientLogin for C2DM? I want to make the application experience as seamless as possible even for users who have 2-step verification enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The account that gets authenticated with C2DM is the pole account that you provided when you signed up for C2DM.  As long as that account does not use 2-step verification, everything is fine.  It does not use the user's credentials.

Rather, it does not use the user's credentials to push messages.  The user must be signed in to Google services on their Android device, but they set that up on their own time.  Once it is set up, everything looks the same to you as a developer.

Comment: Excellent! I just found [a very useful](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-c2dm-messaging-server-push-for.html) article explaining all this in detail. The C2DM is quite iffy.

Comment: Great! I have C2DM implemented in my app currently, but I haven't released it yet.  I've hit the production quota a few times, but it seems to work very well otherwise (especially for a service that's still in Beta testing).

Comment: I meant to say the C2DM **documentation** is quite iffy :)

Comment: Ah, in that case I completely agree. ;)