# C2DM with ClientLogin deprecated

Tags: android, android-c2dm

Now when the ClientLogin authentication is deprecated should we use OAuth 2.0 for C2DM messaging?

My application is C# web app that needs to send messages to registered devices. Any example how to get an Auth Token with OAuth to use with C2dm messaging? Which type of authentication I need to use (Installed Applications, Web Server...)?

**Edited 28 Jun, 2012**

C2DM is deprecated. Developers are encouraged to switch to GCM, C2DM will be supported for a short time. Simple API instead of ClientLogin and oAuth2 which are not supported.
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android C2DM still requires that you use Client Login authorization. oAuth 2.0 is not available for C2DM yet so implement Client Login. As Warpzit says Google's deprecation policy states that it does not apply to experimental features, and cloud to device messaging is still considered to be in the "labs" state.

Comment: Any link to a trusted resource?

Comment: There are a few SO threads on this. I havent seen anything official from Google yet.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340005/c2dm-with-php-using-oauth2-0-clientlogin-is-deprecated
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222850/is-android-cloud-2-device-messaging-c2dm-compatible-with-googles-2-step-verif

Comment: ClintLogin is not an experemental service it is a product and standard deprecation policy rule applies, 3 years until April 20, 2015 (https://developers.google.com/accounts/terms). Alongside there are more mentions appear that there is no support yet for Server App support for oAuth2. I'm accepting you answer.

Comment: C2DM is deprecated. Developers are encouraged to switch to GCM, C2DM will be supported for a short time

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion here: [C2DM with PHP using OAuth2.0 (ClientLogin is deprecated!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340005/c2dm-with-php-using-oauth2-0-clientlogin-is-deprecated)

I'd assume that since android C2DM still is part of labs (meaning experimental) it still runs clientlogin and wont be deprecated any time soon. A snippet from the deprecation policy states:

> This Deprecation Policy doesn't apply to versions, features, and
>   functionality labeled as "experimental.

But since it still is experimental we all have a much more serious issue, will google completely pull the plug on C2DM?

Comment: I saw that thread but thanks for trying. I asked this question on android office hours hangout yesterday and somebody(apparently Google's employee) said OAuth already in use but no implementation examples available yet.